# How to convert files in Formidable Incomming form to base64

Tags: node.js, next.js, odoo, base64, formidable

im building a `next` js project, basically it gets data from the client (form) and send it to the server through http request `(axios)` and then use `xmlrpc` to send it to `odoo` erp
the thing is that the form has files on it, what i want to do is send data and the files directly to odoo without storing them in my server, nota that odoo accepts only files with `base64 encoding`,
here is my frontend code

```js
    const SubmitHandeler = (values) => {
        const formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('nom', values.nom);
        formdata.append('prenom', values.prenom);
        formdata.append('email', values.email);
        formdata.append('phone', values.phone);
        values.files.forEach((file) => {
            formdata.append(`file`, file);
        });
        setUploading(true);
        axios.post("/api/upload", formdata, {
            onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                const progressPercent = Math.round(
                    (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
                );
                setProgress(progressPercent);
            },
        }).then((result) => {
            setUploading(false);
            // router.push('/');
            console.log(result.data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            setUploading(false);
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
```

for my backend code, ive used `formidable` to parse the request, as u can see next, in the encoding option in the `formidable.IncomingForm constructor`, if i specify the format to `base64`, the resolved array of files will be empty (dont know why) but if i dont specify the encoding, the array of files got some actual files that i can store and i can work with them normally, but cant convert them into base64 although files in formidable `(type : formidable.File)` has a `.toString()` method but it doesnt let u specify the encoding (in fs for example we can do `file.toString("base64")` ), but in formidable we cant

```js
export default async function handeler(req, res) {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm({ multiples: true, encoding: "base64" });

    const formData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) {
                reject("error");
            }
            resolve({ fields, files });
        });
    });


    const { fields, files } = await formData;
    //SEND TO ODOO
    send_data_to_odoo(/*args*/)
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "done" })
}
```

- ive tried multer : dont suit me since multer stores files on the fs and i dont want that
- ive tried converting to base64 both in the frontend using `js const base64String = Buffer.from(fileData).toString('base64');` but that didnt work
- ive tried to use `file.toString()` hoping odoo accepts it but no

Answer (score 2):

You can use [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa) to convert to the base64 format a string, and [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob) to decode a string from the base64 format.

In your next.js app (the frontend part), it looks like you aren't encoding the file to the base64 format, so you don't need to use `encoding: "base64"` on your api endpoint. Thus you should encode it on the backend.

```js
export default async function handeler(req, res) {

    // you don't need to convert the files
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm({ multiples: true });

    const formData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) {
                reject("error");
            }
            resolve({ fields, files });
        });
    });


    const { fields, files } = await formData;

    // you convert each file to base64 format
    for (const file in files) {
      files[file] = btoa(files[file]);
    }

    //SEND TO ODOO
    send_data_to_odoo(/*args*/)
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "done" })
}
```

You can also verify that the file is not already encoded in base64 format with

```js
let isBase64 = false;
try {
  // if you can convert the file from the base64 format, then the file is already encoded
  atob(files[file]);
  isBase64 = true;
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Already base64 format');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and then use the Buffer `toString()` method passing `"base64"` as param.

Try this:

```js
const formData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      reject("error");
    }

    Object.values(files).forEach((file) => {
      const buffer = fs.readFileSync(file.filepath);
      const base64 = buffer.toString("base64");
      console.log("File base64", base64.slice(0, 10));
    });
    
  });
});
```

Comment: hey, im using vercel to deploy this nextjs application, ur approche works fine on my machine, but it cant be font there (file.path returns a path in the temp in my machine and tmp/ in prod in vercel), vercel doesnt allow me to read or to write files even from from /tmp, ive found this https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions but didnt work for me, or id didnt implement it correctly